# Specific activity vs turnover number of enzymes in BRENDA

Tags: enzymes, database, enzyme-kinetics

From my understanding, the specific activity (A, units: umol/min/mg protein) can be derived from the turnover number (k, units: 1/seg) and the molar mass of an enzyme (MW, units: g/mol):

A = k / MW / 60000

When I try to do this for several entries in the BRENDA database, I don't get an agreement, sometimes the equality is off by an order of magnitude.
However I understand that there can be experimental errors involved, or I might be using the wrong MW (sometimes it is not clear what specific protein the value refers to).

Am I doing something wrong in this calculation?